# Android : Image is not display in Image-view From Camera

Tags: android

I'm implementing camera application. I captured the image from camera and save it into DCIM folder and show that image into ImageView.The image is getting stored into DCIM  folder successfully but does not show in ImageView with full screen size . And my application is crash and getting error of

> Uri selectedImageUri  = data.getData();  is null object reference.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button b1,b2;
    ImageView iv;private File output=null;int CONTENT_REQUEST =9999;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

                output = new File(dir, "CameraContentDemo.jpeg");

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(output));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CONTENT_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(urImageFilePath);
        if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                try{
                    Uri selectedImageUri  = data.getData();
                    Log.e("selectedImageUri "," = " + selectedImageUri);
                    if(selectedImageUri!=null){

                        Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri));
                        Log.e("bmp "," = " + bmp);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        Log.e("bmp ", " Displaying Imageview WIth Bitmap !!!!  = ");
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
                {
                    fe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }}
```

Here is camera permission in Menifest.xml File

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Here is my Logcat error

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9999, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.tazeen.demo3/com.example.tazeen.demo3.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3568)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.tazeen.demo3.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:55)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3564)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1345)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
11-23 15:10:34.367     647-1092/? E/ActivityManager﹕ Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 384x384
```

Comment: \ <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I this two syntax in menifest file but getting same error =     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.tazeen.demo3.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:55)

Comment: its returning null actually

Comment: can you post the logcat for the nullpointer exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the bitmap taken from camera intent will not be present in `data.getData()`, if you had chosen a file which is already in disk then `data.getData()` would be an URI to the file resource. The picture taken from Camera activity is not stored but is kept as Bitmap in memory, and is passed to the parent activity's onActivityResult in the intent's extras, the way you get this bitmap is like so

`data.getExtras().get("data");`

So the change in your code would be this,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(urImageFilePath);
        if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                try{
                    Uri selectedImageUri  = data.getData();
                    Log.e("selectedImageUri "," = " + selectedImageUri);
                    if(selectedImageUri!=null){

                        Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri));
                        Log.e("bmp "," = " + bmp);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                        Log.e("bmp ", " Displaying Imageview WIth Bitmap !!!!  = ");
                    } else {
                        // If selectedImageUri is null check extras for bitmap
                        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException fe)
                {
                    fe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }}
```

**EDIT 1**

This is how you make the intent to launch the camera activity for result,

```
final int CHOOSE_CAMERA = 232;
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CHOOSE_CAMERA);
```

Comment: @p.ld Oh so `data` itself is null?